# Embed a Visualforce page in a Standard Creation Layout

Tags: visualforce

I know it is possible to embed a VF page into the edit page layout, but it is possible to do it in the form when you are creating a new record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You would need to override the New button with a Visualforce page instead.